# Angular 2 Staggering Animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

Angular 2 RC2 just came out and I am wondering whether it already supports staggered animations for `*ngFor`? The DSL language documentation mentions `group` and `sequence` but no stagger of any kind?

Is staggered animation not included in RC2?

Comment: take a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40858203/5612697)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I agree with Günter that the ng-conf features are in the newest RC.3 or for that matter in the RC.4 release. A stagger feature would be excellent but as of current that doesn't look like it's slated for RC.5. It will definitely be in the `Angular 2 Final` release as you can see on this animation tracking [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7478). With that being said though I did create a workaround for my application I would be willing to share. There might be an easier approach but this works:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: `<div @fadeIn="state">This is my content</div>`,
    animations: [
        trigger('fadeIn', [
            state('inactive', style({opacity:0})),
            state('active', style({opacity:1)})),
            transition('inactive => active', [
                animate('500ms ease-in')
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
export class Child implements OnInit {
    @Input() delay;

    constructor() {
        this.state = 'inactive';
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sleep(this.delay).then(() => {
            this.state = 'active';
        };
    }
    // HELPER*
    sleep(time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    templateUrl: `
        <div *ngFor="let child of children">
            <child [delay]="child.delay"></child>
        </div>
    `
})
export class Child implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        this.children = [];
        this.children.push({ delay: 600 });
        this.children.push({ delay: 1200 });
    }
}
```

Like I said maybe not the simplest way but it works for me. Hope it helps you!

*HELPER: [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Looks like it has been released: https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger

Answer (score 0):

They are working on it, as we can see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr4IKlr9mhg&feature=youtu.be&t=10m50s

But I think it was not released yet... We need to wait a little more :-(

Here there is the examples that we see in the video... but I don't know if this is a stable version... at your own risk
https://github.com/matsko/ng-conf-demos

Comment: The animation module demonstrated at ng-conf is included in Angular2 RC.3

Comment: sorry for the push. But any updates on this? Is stagger (ng-conf-demos) still valid? If not is there a plunker available?