# Angular 4 Animate the newly added element of an array

Tags: angular, animation

I have a div where I have some values in an array displayed in it and I can add more. The newly added value will be added directly to the div:

```
list = ['milk', 'sugar', 'flour'];
    
state = 'normal';

//@ViewChild('f') addForm: NgForm;

onAdd(item)
  {
    this.list.push(item);
    //this.addForm.reset();
  }
```

I have this simple animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('divState', [
        state('normal', style({
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            transform: 'translateX(0)'
        })),
        state('highlighted', style({
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            transform: 'translateX(100px)'
        })),
        transition('normal=>highlighted', animate(300)),
        transition('highlighted=>normal', animate(800))
    ])
  ]
```

That is applied to a div, where it will be animate it.

What I really need is to apply a flashing red color, to the newly added value of the array for few milliseconds like flash.

So if I have the following:

> Milk
>
> Sugar
>
> Flour

And then added Eggs:

> Milk
>
> Sugar
>
> Flour
>
> Eggs

And the Eggs div should flash.

I know that I should work on the index, by getting the last added index and apply the animation on it:

```
<li 
  class="list-group-item"
  
  *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
  {{ item }}
</li>
```

I tried the following:

```
<li [@divState]="state"
  class="list-group-item"
  
  *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
  {{ item }}
</li>
```

So all the divs are highlighted.

How can apply this animation (basically I am not focusing on the animation as itself so I will apply a simple red color to it) using the index so by that, I can show the newly added element of the array.

Comment: You can certainly write your own answer and accept it if it's complete.

Comment: Did you able to find the solution

Comment: Yes. The newely added element will be animated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I get the animation from [Angular 2 animate *ngFor list item one after other using new Animation support in RC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085837/angular-2-animate-ngfor-list-item-one-after-other-using-new-animation-support-i?answertab=votes#tab-top).

The solution is that the animation could be applied normally to any element of `ngFor` by simply adding the property of the trigger as adding it into another element.

So here are the scripts:

```
animations: [
    trigger('divState', [
      state('in', style({backgroundColor: 'red',transform: 'translateX(0)'})),

      transition('void => *', [
        animate(1000, keyframes([
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)', offset: 0}),
          style({backgroundColor: '#bee0ff',opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(15px)',  offset: 0.3}),
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 1.0})
        ]))
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(300, keyframes([
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 0}),
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(-15px)', offset: 0.7}),
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(100%)',  offset: 1.0})
        ]))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

And here is the array displayed:

```
<li  [@divState]="state"
   class="list-group-item"
   (click)="onDelete(item)"
   *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
   {{ item }}
</li>
```

[Here is a plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/WCdpidlyByiqdCzHwQ3T/).

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43344231/2) to the question [Angular 4 Animate the newly added element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344231/angular-4-animate-the-newly-added-element-of-an-array) by the OP [alim1990](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3922727/alim1990) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>