# How to make delay between each animation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, css-animations, angular2-animation

I made some changes in `Angular2` animation example in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e9GoH3ApfZtR0cXfsGRF?p=preview)

I want to make animations in a way that when I click on `Add All Heros` or `Remove All Heroes` each item comes or goes during the prev one, right now they all come or go with each other. I have no idea how can I make delays in angular2.

Something list `list` demo in this site http://ionicmaterial.com/

ps. There is `done` event that I can add each item when the prev is done but I want them to begin with delays while the prev one is still animating

Comment: I think they are using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: You are probably looking for Staggering angular2 animations. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702396/staggering-angular2-animations-within-ngfor

Comment: @Obaid Yes, that is the good one